# SignalR - Cannot get username

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, signalr

Building chat application using SignalR, I'm new with SignalR, started with [Tutorial: Getting Started with SignalR 2 and MVC 5](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-and-mvc)

Everything passed fine, now I want impliment Application User Name as sender, when I use method like this:

```
$('#displayname').val('@Context.User.Identity.Name');
```

Hub gets current loged in username and displays it on  page,  here is my Hub Code:

```
[HubName("chatHub")]
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    public void Send(string name, string message)
    {
        Clients.All.addNewMessageToPage(name, message);
    }

}
```

Now I want impliment username with another method,  this method is described [Here](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server)

Code below not working,  can  anyone explain why, I want to  understant to know method how to  use SingalR.
Here is code that not works:

```
[HubName("chatHub")]
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    public void Send(string name, string message)
    {
        name = Context.User.Identity.Name;
        Clients.All.addNewMessageToPage(name, message);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your startup class did you configure auth ?

With something like this :

```
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration { EnableDetailedErrors = true };
        ConfigureAuth(app);
        app.MapSignalR(hubConfiguration);
    }
```

The following code is autogenerated when you create a new MCV project with authentication.

```
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {

        // Configure the db context, user manager and signin manager to use a single instance per request
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<AppUserManager>(AppUserManager.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<AppRoleManager>(AppRoleManager.Create);

        // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
        // and to use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
        // Configure the sign in cookie
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {

             ...
        }
}
```